# How to attribute a value to a character in an element of an array (Python)

Tags: python, arrays

```
spades = ['2S','3S','4S','5S','6S','7S','8S','9S','10S','JS','QS','KS','AS']
hearts = ['2H','3H','4H','5H','6H','7H','8H','9H','10H','JH','QH','KH','AH']
clubs = ['2C','3C','4C','5C','6C','7C','8C','9C','10C','JC','QC','KC','AC']
diamonds = ['2D','3D','4D','5D','6D','7D','8D','9D','10D','JD','QD','KD','AD']

suits = [spades,hearts,clubs,diamonds]
```

How would I go about attributing a value to the strength of the card. i.e 5S = 5, JS=11, AS=14.

Comment: What do you mean `attributing a value`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a [dictionary](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries):

```
card_values = {
    '5S': 5,
    'JS': 11,
    'AS': 14,
    # Etc.
}
```

Then retrieve the associated value using `card_values["5S"]` for example.

Answer (score 0):

I think the separation of card types (2 to 10, J, Q, K, A) and card suits is way more cleaner.
This way, you don't have to worry about the numbering or typos in the suits.

```
card_types = ['2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '10', 'J', 'Q', 'K', 'A']
spades = [card + "S" for card in card_types]
hearts = [card + "H" for card in card_types]
clubs = [card + "C" for card in card_types]
diamonds = [card + "D" for card in card_types]

suits = [spades, hearts, clubs, diamonds]

card_strengths = {'J': 11,
          'Q': 12,
          'K': 13,
          'A': 14
}


def get_strength(card):
    rank = card[0]
    if rank.isdigit():
    return int(rank)
    return card_strengths[rank]


if __name__ == "__main__":
    print get_strength('3S')
    print get_strength('JS')
    print get_strength('AC')
```

Output:

> 3
>   11
>   14

Answer (score 0):

Using `dictionary` key-value pair for each an every value isn't nice solution. For this particular situation, you can achieve what do you want with a simple solution.

See the pattern,

```
list_index:0   value:2
list_index:1   value:3
list_index:2   value:4  
............   .......
list_index:12  value:14
```

Use this pattern to find an easier solution.

```
value = spades.index('5S')+2 
value =  diamonds.index('AD')+2
```

From this, you would get the intuition i hope.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want a function..

```
   def get_card_value(card_str):
       value = card_str[0]
       face_values = { 'A':14,
                       'K':13,
                       'Q':12,
                       'J':11 }
       if value.upper() in face_values:
          return face_values[value.upper()]
       else:
          return int(value)
```

Then you can just call it

```
print(get_card_value(hearts[2]))
```